# Error no 1604 while adding notes in database with concat() query in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ddUpj.png)[Codeigniter show following error when we add form data using textarea field.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dknlw.png)
I am trying to Add notes to use following functions in CI model and getting error Please help to resolve this problem.

```
function add_note($id,$customer_comment){
     $this->db->where('customer_id',$id);
    $this->db->set('customer_comment', " CONCAT(customer_comment,',',' ".$customer_comment."')", FALSE);
    $this->db->update('tbl_customer');
    echo "<script>
        window.location.href='".base_url()."index.php/login_ctrl/add_notes?customer_id=".$id."';
        </script>"; 

}
```

Comment: What do you want to concat exactly?, it seems you have too many quotes and commas in that concat

Comment: By the image, it looks like the comment you are trying to add has a single quote inside, breaking the query, please escape your inputs, prepare your queries or use CI database functions for escaping and bindings http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html

Comment: I want to update data in a field but previous data in that field remain same and new data should be add below previous data.

Comment: please tell me if there is another query to update data like this. for example if a field already have (hello) this word and Now I want to add (how are you) it should be (hello how are you) in same field

Comment: In the comment you are trying to add (from your screenshot), there is a part that says .... cancun doesn't release ... there is a quote there, and sql interpret that as the end of that block, breaking the query, your code is not safe, you can't directly use user's input in your queries.

Comment: your logic is fine, the way you are adding the data is correct by your db structure, if you try to add a simple comment like hello it will work, the problem is that is not safe, please read some docs about SQL Injection etc

Comment: Thanks for reply Its working fine